# How to merge SQL Server 2012 Express setup with .NET windows application setup?

Tags: .net, sql-server

How to merge SQL Server 2012 Express with a .NET windows application setup or exe?
And please give me the link of SQL Server 2012 Express downloading.

Comment: See : http://bit.ly/SY36AN

Answer (score 4):

Simple: YOU DO NOT. Merging Setups sucks - you lose the capability to update / maintain them.

What you do is having a bootstrap application that installs the SQL Server express Standard Setup before installing your application.

Look at visual Studio - it does the same. All the prerequisites it installs are there in unmodified form, the wrapper application (the exe you start) just calls them to install them.

Currently the only real way to make installers (WIX toolset) has a bootstrap mechanism for this.